# A word to describe someone who has moved back to live in his/her home country?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

If a person was born and brought up in country **A**, at some point went to live in country **B** (as an adult) for a few years and then moved back to country **A**, is there a single word to describe that person's situation?

Comment: He/She is **back home**!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The OED has the noun *repatriate* to mean someone who has been restored to their (own or original) country.  Examples given there include:

- The majority of these **repatriates** have the choice of living on totally inadequate means or entering the workhouse.
- Seven ships have been named as bringing **repatriates** home to Britain.
- Mrs Meir, the Prime Minister, and··the Defence Minister, were among those at Lod airport today to give the **repatriates** a heroes’ welcome.

Comment: I don't believe it has that connotation at all.

Comment: @camden_kid That would be closer to a [deportee](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deportee). ODO has a helpful entry for [repatriate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repatriate).

Comment: @coleopterist Though that would be out of a country. You'd have to mangle some Latin and get an adportee. :P

Comment: I'm hesitant about marking this as the answer because it doesn't 'feel' right but also the three examples indicate external forces influencing the return of the repatriates.

Comment: @camden_kid If you look at the examples for the verb, whence the noun derives, there is no theme of some sort of **forced** repatriation.  It might be that they had been in exile, or rescued, or many other things.

Answer (score 4):

*Remigrant* comes to mind.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remigrant):

> REMIGRANT: a migrant who returns

Comment: *Remigrant*. Does not appear in Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

It is not often used as a noun, (at least not compared to (a) its opposite, *expatriate*, nor (b) the verb form *repatriate*, [the important pronunciation difference being, I think--and there may be UK/N Am differences here--that the verb has stress on the second syllable and pronounces it--re-PAY-tri-ate, and the noun, while also stressing the second syllable, pronouns it--re-PA-tri-ate.  Be that as it may, the best noun I can come up with is *repatriate*.

I am Canadian, and for example, a decade ago, an *expatriate Canadian*, Michael Ignatieff, moved back to Canada after a twenty or thirty year absence living and working in America and the U.K., in order to become the leader of the Canadian Liberal Party.  You could say he *repatriated* himself, or that he became a *repatriate*.  (Ignatieff's story did not end well; after losing two federal Canadian elections, Ignatieff resigned from politics and currently serves as a professor at the University of Toronto.  His extended expatriate status was a huge issue in both of the elections he lost; it is an illustrative example of how to use these terms.)

Comment: +1 for the first 8 words, which are significantly missing from the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about repat? It would be the opposite of expat.

Comment: Not bad :-) I prefer it to repatriate but I'm not sure it's a word in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

*Returned emigrant*, which does imply someone away for years, in double figures perhaps.